# Como vejo as coordenadas do mouse na tela?

Tags: python, coordenadas, pyautogui

Estou aprendendo sobre a lib pyautogui do Python e nisso gostaria de saber exatamente onde está o ponteiro do mouse para poder efetuar o click com precisão.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar a função .position() do pyautogui para obter o x e y do ponteiro em relação a tela. por exemplo:

```
print(pyautogui.position())
```

Recomendo que utilize essa função com o sleep para dar tempo de você colocar o ponteiro em cima do botão.

Caso queira um click ainda mais preciso recomendo você utilizar a função .locateCenterOnScreen ou .locateAllOnScreen. Você consegue ver mais sobre essas funções na documentação do pyautogui:
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html